# Dataframe transformation with specific character

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Below is my python code on a data which I have created.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.2454235445,2],
               [3,4.452455]],
               columns = ['A','B'])
```

This outputs to-

```
   A         B
0  1.245424  2.000000
1  3.000000  4.452455
```

However, I would like to have this output structured in this format-

```
|A         |B         |
| 1.245424 | 2.000000 |
| 3.000000 | 4.452455 |
```

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: @KarlThornton Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose could be used e.g. [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/):

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  [1.2454235445,2],
  [3,4.452455]],
  columns = ['A','B']
)

print(tabulate(df, headers = df.columns, tablefmt = 'pipe', showindex = False))
```

Output:

```
|       A |       B |
|--------:|--------:|
| 1.24542 | 2       |
| 3       | 4.45245 |
```

It has numerous table formats (set via parameter `tablefmt`) allowing to change table style.

Comment: This helped a lot.
I have seen the documentation of tabulate and github format was more close to what I was looking for.
Here is the same for your reference- https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/